# Bluemix Session Cache: Trigger to evict cached data

Tags: ibm-cloud, session-cache, websphere-extreme-scale

I create Java web app on IBM Bluemix.  This application shares session object among instances via Session Cache Service.

I understand how to program my application with session cache. But I could not find any descriptions if the total amount of cached data exceeds cache space (e.g. for starter plan, I can use 1GB cache space.).

These are my questions.

Q1. Are there any trigger to remove cached data from cache space?

Q2. After exceeding cache space, what data will be removed?  Is there any cache strategy such as Least Recently Used, Least Frequently Used and so on?

Answer (score 0):

The [Session Cache service on IBM Bluemix](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SessionCache/index.html) is based on WebSphere Extreme Scale. Hence a lot of background information is provided in the [Knowledge Center of WebSphere Extreme Scale](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTVLU_8.6.0/com.ibm.websphere.extremescale.doc/kc_welcome-xs.html). The standard [Liberty profile for the Session Cache](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTVLU_8.6.0/com.ibm.websphere.extremescale.doc/rxslibertywebapp.html) uses a Least Recently Used (LRU) algorithm to manage the space. I haven't tried it yet, but the first linked document describes how to monitor the cache and obtain statistics.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I'll check Knowledge Center of WXS.